# Difficulty on the integration of Paypal on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, paypal, paypal-sandbox

This is my first time to implement Paypal on my project. I am using [srmklive/laravel-paypal](https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal) and on the documentation I tested the following code

This is my controller:

```
class CheckoutController extends Controller
{
    protected $provider;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->provider = new ExpressCheckout();
    }

    public function getExpressCheckout(Request $request){
        $data = [];
        $data['items'] = [
          [
            'name' => 'Product 1',
            'price' => 9.99,
            'qty' => 1
          ],
          [
            'name' => 'Product 2',
            'price' => 4.99,
            'qty' => 2
          ]
        ];

        $data['invoice_id'] = 2;
        $data['invoice_description'] = "test";
        $data['return_url'] = url('/');
        $data['cancel_url'] = url('/cart');

        $total = 0;
        foreach($data['items'] as $item) {
            $total += $item['price']*$item['qty'];
        }

        $data['total'] = $total;

        //give a discount of 10% of the order amount
        $data['shipping_discount'] = round((10 / 100) * $total, 2);
        $response = $this->provider->setExpressCheckout($data);
        return redirect($response['paypal_link']);
    }
 }
```

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/paypal/ec-checkout', 'CheckoutController@getExpressCheckout')->name('checkout');
```

This is my link:

```
 <a href="{{ route('checkout') }}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-bottom:20px;">Checkout</a>
```

My problem is when I click the link it just loads forever and no errors are displayed. I am using `Laravel 5.6`

Comment: Try do print the response before redirect.. dd($response)

Comment: i tried to do that before i don't understand why it keeps loading endless even if i put it before redirect

Comment: So the set express checkout method loads forever?

Comment: Use omnipay.. much better

Comment: is omnipay works on 5.6?

Comment: yeah i think also that the set express checkout method is the problem or maybe im doing something wrong

Comment: Omnipay should work on 5.6 yes

Comment: is this it? https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-omnipay

Comment: Yes, much more stars